Explicit formula for power sums with bounded indices
The power sums:
$$\sum_{1\le m_1+m_2+\dots+m_k\le n}a_1^{m_1}a_2^{m_2}\dots a_k^{m_k}$$
Where $m_1,\dots,m_k$ are natural numbers, for $k=1$ it is simply
$$\frac{a_1(a_1^n-1)}{a_1-1}$$
But I can't figure out formula for higher $k$.
Edit: I think this formula is true
$$\sum_{m_1+m_2+\dots+m_k=n}a_1^{m_1}a_2^{m_2}\dots a_k^{m_k}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{a_i^{n+k-1}}{\prod\limits_{j=1, j\neq i}^{k}a_i-a_j}$$
And tried to prove it by induction:
$$\sum_{m_1+m_2+\dots+m_k+m_{k+1}=n}a_1^{m_1}a_2^{m_2}\dots a_k^{m_k}a_{k+1}^{m_{k+1}}$$
$$=\sum_{m_{k+1}=0}^na_{k+1}^{m_{k+1}}\sum_{m_1+m_2+\dots+m_k=n-m_{k+1}}a_1^{m_1}a_2^{m_2}\dots a_k^{m_k}$$
$$=\sum_{m_{k+1}=0}^na_{k+1}^{m_{k+1}}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{a_i^{n-m_{k+1}+k-1}}{\prod\limits_{j=1, j\neq i}^{k}a_i-a_j}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i^{k-1}\frac{\sum\limits_{m_{k+1}=0}^na_{k+1}^{m_{k+1}}a_i^{n-m_{k+1}}}{\prod\limits_{j=1, j\neq i}^{k}a_i-a_j}$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i^{k-1}\frac{\frac{a_i^{n+1}-a_{k+1}^{n+1}}{a_i-a_{k+1}}}{\prod\limits_{j=1, j\neq i}^{k}a_i-a_j}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i^{k-1}\frac{a_i^{n+1}-a_{k+1}^{n+1}}{\prod\limits_{j=1, j\neq i}^{k+1}a_i-a_j}$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{a_i^{n+k}}{\prod\limits_{j=1, j\neq i}^{k+1}a_i-a_j}-\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{a_i^{k-1}a_{k+1}^{n+1}}{\prod\limits_{j=1, j\neq i}^{k+1}a_i-a_j}$$
So it suffices to prove that:
$$-\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{a_i^{k-1}a_{k+1}^{n+1}}{\prod\limits_{j=1, j\neq i}^{k+1}a_i-a_j}=\frac{a_{k+1}^{n+k}}{\prod\limits_{j=1, j\neq k+1}^{k+1}a_{k+1}-a_j}$$
Or equivalently:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{a_i^{k-1}}{\prod\limits_{j=1, j\neq i}^{k+1}a_i-a_j}=0\qquad(*)$$
Question: Is the formula above correct? How to prove $(*)$?

Can $m_i$ be negative? If so then there'll be an infinite number of such terms.

@CosmicOscillator Sorry for my mistakes, i edited the question

Since I found a proof of $(*)$, I'll post it here
Let $Q(x)=x^k$ and $\ell_i(x)=\prod\limits_{j=1,j\neq i}^{k+1}\frac{x-a_j}{a_i-a_j}$ be basis polynomials of $Q(x)$. Then
$$Q(x)=x^k=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}Q(a_i)\ell_i(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}a_i^k\ell_i(x)$$
Then at $x=0$:
$$Q(0)=0=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}a_i^k\ell_i(0)=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}a_i^k\cdot\prod_{j=1,j\neq i}^{k+1}\frac{-a_j}{a_i-a_j}$$
$$\implies \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{a_i^{k-1}}{\prod\limits_{j=1, j\neq i}^{k+1}a_i-a_j}=0$$
Thus the proof is completed.
And
$$\sum_{1\le m_1+m_2+\dots+m_k\le n}a_1^{m_1}a_2^{m_2}\dots a_k^{m_k}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{\sum\limits_{\ell=1}^{n}a_i^{\ell+k-1}}{\prod_{j=1,j\neq i}^{k}a_i-a_j}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{a_i^k(a_i^n-1)}{(a_i-1)\prod_{j=1,j\neq i}^{k}a_i-a_j}$$

At least for $k = 2$ the computation is short: First, the terms of total degree $i$ have sum
$$\sum_{p + q = i} a^p b^q = \frac{a^{1 + i} - b^{1 + i}}{a - b} .$$
As in the case $k = 1$, when a denominator vanishes, we should interpret the quantity in a limiting sense.
The formula when the lower bound on the total degree is $0$ is arguably more natural. We have:
$$\sum_{\color{#bf0000}{0} \leq p + q \leq n} a^p b^q = \sum_{i = \color{#bf0000}{0}}^n \sum_{p + q = i} a^p b^q = \frac1{a - b} \sum_{i = \color{#bf0000}{0}}^n (a^{1 + i} - b^{1 + i}) .$$
We can write the sum in the last expression as a sum of two geometric sequences $\sum_{i=\color{#bf0000}{0}}^n c^{1 + i} = \frac{c (c^{1 + n} - 1)}{c - 1}$, giving
$$\boxed{\sum_{\color{#bf0000}{0} \leq p + q \leq n} a^p b^q = \frac1{a - b}\left(\frac{a (a^{1 + n} - 1)}{a - 1} - \frac{b (b^{1 + n} - 1)}{b - 1}\right)}$$
Of course, to recover the formula when the lower bound on the total degree is $1$, we need only subtract the single term with total degree zero, $a^0 b^0 = 1$:
$$\boxed{\sum_{1 \leq p + q \leq n} a^p b^q = \frac1{a - b}\left(\frac{a (a^{1 + n} - 1)}{a - 1} - \frac{b (b^{1 + n} - 1)}{b - 1}\right) - 1}.$$

Where did you get the formula for $k=2$ from? It might be helpful if I know the original source

I think this answer only works for $k  = 2$, because it's easy to find $\sum_{p+q=k} a^p b^q$ and the sum telescopes. $\quad$ What's the generalization you had in mind for $k = 3$?

@ThinhDinh I've added a short derivation for the $k = 2$ case, though like Calvin wrote it really just amounts to adding up geometric sequences several times.

@CalvinLin The answer only addresses the $k = 2$ case; I don't have a generalization in mind.

The complete homogeneous symmetric polynomial of degree $j$
$$ h_j(a_1,\cdot \cdot,a_k):=\sum_{1 \le i_1 \le \cdot\cdot \le i_j\le k } a_{i_1} \cdot \cdot a_{i_k} $$ also reads
$$ h_j(a_1,\cdot \cdot,a_k)= \sum_{m_1 + \cdot \cdot +m_k= j} a_1^{m_1}\cdot \cdot a_k^{m_k} $$
then $$S_n:=\sum_{0\le m_1+m_2+\dots+m_k\le n}a_1^{m_1}a_2^{m_2}\dots a_k^{m_k}= \sum_{j=0}^n h_j(a_1,\cdot \cdot,a_k).$$
It is unlikely that it can be reduced further for general $n$, except when $m_1+m_2+\dots+m_k$ is left unbounded, and $ \vert{a_i}\vert \lt 1$. Since, the generating function for the complete homogeneous symmetric polynomial is
$$ \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{1-a_it}=\sum_{j\ge 0} h_j(a_1,\cdot \cdot,a_k)t^j, $$
we have $$ S_\infty=\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{1-a_i}.$$

Assume for simplicity that all $a_i$ are distinct and  different of $1.$ Denote $S_n=\sum_{m_1+\cdots+m_k=n}a_1^{m_1}\ldots a_k^{m_k}.$ We have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}S_nz^n=\left(\sum_{m_1=0}^{\infty}(a_1z)^{m_1}\right)\ldots\left(\sum_{m_1=0}^{\infty}(a_kz)^{m_k}\right)$$$$=\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^k(1-a_iz)}=\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{A_i}{(1-a_iz)}$$ where by decomposition of a rational function into partial fractions we have $A_i=\frac{1}{\prod_{j\neq i}(1-\frac{a_j}{a_i})}.$ As a consequence $S_n=A_1a_1^n+\cdots+A_ka_k^n$ and $$S_0+S_1+\cdots+S_n=A_1\frac{a_1^{n+1}-1}{a_1-1}+\cdots+A_k\frac{a_k^{n+1}-1}{a_k-1}.$$
